# Domains to resolve to VM default page with nameservers

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, domain

I have an apache VM with a default page - that I want to be served to all domains / IPs requesting the content (which is setup already).

I have setup nameservers (ns1.example.com & ns2.example.com) and bound them with IP e.g. 202.202.202.202 - this is the main IP of the server.

Assigning these nameservers to different domains, through which they don't resolve and respond with the default landing page content. I understand the IP can be added as wildcard A record for domains where default landing page is to be served.

Is there a way to config the VM in a way where the nameservers method starts to work i.e. for any domains with nameservers (ns1.example.com & ns2.example.com), they should land to default landing page.

Would appreciate if you can put through the approach to be followed.

Comment: This is too confusing to follow.  You need to make it more clear with example domains, example dns zone records, and example urls. Particularly "Assigning these nameservers to different domains, through which they don't resolve and respond with the default landing page content." makes no sense.  Maybe a translation problem?  It isn't clear if the requests are internal or external or what the challenge is